# ionic 2 "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]"

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

There is an ionic 2 project.

Here is my code:

```
export class PostPage {
  posts : [any];

  constructor(private nav:NavController,
    private postSvc: PostService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.postSvc.load()
      .subscribe( data => {
          this.posts = data;
      });
  }
```

The error message is for **this.posts = data**. I defined this.posts as [any]. Also in my PostService I defined the data as [] too.

Code for PostService:

```
load() {
    return new Observable( observer => {

      var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
      var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
      query.find({
        success: results => {
          var data = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            var item = this.createPost(object);
            data.push(item);
          }
          observer.next(data);
          observer.complete();
        },
        error: error => {
          observer.error(error.message);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

I got the error message:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]

As you see, I call **observer.next(data)** where the **data** is []. I don't understand why my ionic 2 think my data is a '{}' . Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For off `posts : [any];` you probably meant `posts : any[];`

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]

This can happen if the TypeScript compiler cannot figure out the type by type inference e.g. if the inferred type is `Promise<{}>` the value passed to `then` will be of type `{}`.

Specify the type in:

```
return new Observable( observer => {
```

e.g:

```
return new Observable<any>( observer => {
```

Comment: For everybody coming here: In my case this solved it: `return new Promise<any[]>(resolve => { ...`